# Inverse of time

Tags: time, frequency

We all know that frequency and time is related using the equation $f=1/T$. there is no any instrument or any theory that can inverse time to measure frequency. Then how is it time related inversely to the frequency?

Comment: $f=1/T$ is the definition of frequency. It is not an experimental relation.

Comment: Most of the digital scopes in the lab seem perfectly happy doing an FFT and presenting you with the frequency domain. Not to mention real parameter analyzers, frequency counters, and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple matter of "it is because we choose to say it is". The frequency of some cycle is a number representing (in standard units) how many cycles occur each second. If you stand with a stopwatch and over one second, you count something happen 2 times, then it has a frequency of 2 cycles per second, or $2Hz$. This is naturally related to period because we logically choose to design it this way. If 2 cycles happen per second, how many seconds does it take for one cycle? Obviously, each cycle must take half a second in order for one full second to have exactly 2 cycles (two halves make a whole). This is represented mathematically as follows:

$$period=\frac{\#~seconds}{1~cycle}$$
To find the number of cycles in 1 second:
$$\frac{1~second}{period}=\frac{1~second}{\frac{\#~seconds}{1~cycle}}=\text{# cycles in one second}$$
But the number of cycles in one second is the same as the number of cycles *per* second, which is exactly what the frequency is.

Perhaps this was a overly trivial way of saying that if we simply take the inverse of a value, the units are inverted as well. Since the units of period are equivalent to the inverse of the units of frequency, it stands to reason you can simply inverse period to get a frequency.

Comment: Nice simple answer! Why the question was down voted (without any comments etc.)!?

Comment: @J.Pak My hypothesis is that people downvoted the question due to its simplicity. But, being a simple answer, I chose to answer it instead

Answer (score 0):

In modern standard physics (see SI units: http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/second.html) time is defined in terms of a periodic phenomenon. But also everyday concepts of time define it that way. For example a day is considered as the time it takes the earth to rotate once. In a way time is merely an auxiliary quantity used to compare the movements of two bodies which one another, whereas at least one of the two movements is typically periodic and has thus a frequency associated with it.